# How to drop elements?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to drop elements completely like so

```
scala> sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).map(x => if(x!="") x).collect
res0: Array[Any] = Array(abc, def, (), ge, (), wer)
```

but as one can see I where not able to drop the "" completely. There is still (). Also not working:

```
scala> sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).map(x => if(x!="") x else None).collect
res1: Array[java.io.Serializable] = Array(abc, def, None, ge, None, wer)
```

or

```
scala> sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).map(x => if(x!="") x else Nil).collect
res2: Array[java.io.Serializable] = Array(abc, def, List(), ge, List(), wer)
```

An alternative would be to use `flatMap` which, as everybody write can return 0 to many elements per original element. But

```
scala> sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).flatMap(x => if(x!="") x else Nil).collect
res3: Array[Char] = Array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, e, w, e, r)


scala> sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).flatMap(x => if(x!="") x).collect
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;                                                                                               
 found   : Unit                                                                                                                  
 required: TraversableOnce[?]                                                         sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).flatMap(x => if(x!="") x).collect
```

How do I get `Array("abc","def","ge","wer")`?

Comment: You can use `filter` instead of using `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sc.parallelize(List("abc","def","","ge","","wer")).filter(!_.isEmpty).collect
```

Answer (score 3):

One way using `flatMap` on `Option`,

```
rdd.flatMap( s => if (s.nonEmpty) Some(s) else None ).collect
```

Comment: Also very nice answer - will come in handy later, as I am sure.